# Why everyone are building tesla coils instead of multipliers?

Tags: high-voltage

When I see someone want to get high voltage - we see tesla coil.

Why everyone do that instead of building [Cockcroft–Walton generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator)? Are there any issues with Cockcroft–Walton generator, making it less fun than tesla coil?

Comment: Like the Wikipedia article says this was invented long before Cockcroft and Walton by a guy named Greinacher. I always refer to it as a **Greinacher multiplier**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's more fun.  Nothing says "mad scientist" like big coils, a few jacob's ladders around the place, sparks flying off towards the sky, and a visible corona.  Some of these things don't work with DC, and a few diodes and capacitors aren't nearly as awe inspiring.

Answer (score 10):

Mostly, the tesla coil is simpler than the multiplier.

To raise the output voltage of the Cockroft-Walton generator, you need to increase the number of stages and/or the voltage rating of the diodes. To do the same for the tesla coil, it simply requires a bigger coil.

Answer (score 7):

The way I understand it, a CW Generator creates high voltage DC, whereas a tesla coil create high voltage AC.

For the fun sparky effects it is easier to use AC that DC as it should spark at a lower voltage.

Also, to get a CW generator up to the kind of voltages that a tesla coil typically gets to (say half a million volts) would take a lot of stages and be quite hard to make.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's the added bonus that the Tesla coil makes lots of noise. The old school spark-gap ones buzz rather loudly, and it's even possible with solid state drive to make a TC emit audio signals from the discharge.

Comment: +1 for Singing Tesla coils [a](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singing_Tesla_coil), [b](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/10-of-the-best-tesla-coils-music-videos-on-youtube/), [c](http://www.stevehv.4hv.org/MusicalSSTCs.htm), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Tesla Coils are marginally less dangerous due to the "Skin Effect" whereas a C.W. Multiplier can become deadly pretty quickly. Also, having a constant stream of arcs, that loud buzz, and the smell of ozone is an experience that a Tesla Coil is quite adept at providing! Besides, a Tesla Coil looks a lot like the universally recognized "Ray Gun"!

Answer (score 0):

A tesla coil uses resonance ,and the q of the secondary multiplies the reactive watts. The reactive output of a tesla coil at 500kv at 8 amps is 4 Mega Watts. Though its not true power ,what your seeing is the reactive power entering the capacitance of air. A voltage multiplier is just true power being stored and discharged.